# Replace observations with NA based on presence of unwanted combinations of variables

Tags: r

The starting data is a numeric matrix with missing values, and a 2 column dataframe that contains combinations of variables that I never want to exist together. The goal is to replace cells in the numeric matrix with NA based on the presence of unwanted combinations of variables. The removal should also occur in an order such that the least number of variables are removed to avoid any of the "bad" combinations.

An example should help clarify. I start with the following:

```
set.seed(1221)
dat <- matrix(rep(1, 16), ncol=4)

colnames(dat) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")

dat[sample(length(dat),3)] <- NA

bad_combos <- data.frame(Var1 = c("V1", "V3"), Var2 = c("V2", "V4"))
```

Here "dat" is my matrix, and "bad_combos" gives pairs of variable names that I do NOT want to ever co-occur. So in this case, variables "V1" and "V2" should never both be non-NA, and "V3" and "V4" should never both be non-NA.

I have come up with a poor solution that fails to scale up for my real dataset (also suffers from memory problems). It uses a for loop to go through each row, uses an inner join to come up with problematic overlapping rows, and then starts replacing cells with NA accordingly. I use table() and which.max() to ensure that I start by removing the most common problem variables first to minimize what is removed (if there is no difference, as in the case here, then it just removes the first case which is fine).

```
for(i in 1:dim(dat)[1]) {
  resp.cols <- colnames(dat)[which(!is.na(dat[i,]))]
  eg <- expand.grid(resp.cols, resp.cols)
  vars <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::inner_join(bad_combos[, c("Var1", "Var2")], eg, by=c("Var1", "Var2")) )
  dat.sort <- t(apply(vars, 1, sort))
  vars <- vars[!duplicated(dat.sort),]

  if(dim(vars)[1] != 0) {
    done <- FALSE

    while(done == FALSE){
      remove <- names(which.max(table(c(vars$Var1, vars$Var2))))

      dat[i, remove] <- NA #make this one appear missing
      print("got one")
      vars <- vars[-which(vars$Var1 == remove | vars$Var2 == remove),]

      if(dim(vars)[1] == 0) done <- TRUE
    } 
  } 
}
```

Currently this function achieves the desired result, which is that "dat" has the correct cells replaced with NA such that none of the bad combinations exist. But it is awfully inefficient, which is problematic because I need it to work on a matrix with 60 columns and 20,000 rows. I feel like there must be an elegant solution possible?

Comment: Don't get your criteria for "start by removing the most common problem variables" especially since your sample data doesn't demonstrate it. In case this is helpful `dat[!is.na(dat[,'V1']) & !is.na(dat[,'V2']),'V1'] = NA` would set V1 to NA whenever you see non-na V1 and V2, so you can loop around `bad_combos` instead of dat. You can split the subset based on your criteria for frequencies.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. The problem is demonstrated if: `bad_combos <- data.frame(Var1 = c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V3"), Var2 = c("V2", "V3", "V4", "V4"))` -- in this case I definitely want V1 to be removed in the first row, and either of V3 or V4. But not V3 and V4 (which would satisy the overall criterion, but ignores the fact that V1 conflicts with more variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your bad combos always happens in pairs, then you look at one pair at time, which is something like your for-loop. For one pair, you can only replace with NAs, those rows that have no NAs in the pair associated column:

```
set.seed(1221)
dat <- matrix(rep(1, 16), ncol=4)

colnames(dat) <- c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")

dat[sample(length(dat),3)] <- NA

bad_combos <- data.frame(Var1 = c("V1", "V3"), Var2 = c("V2", "V4"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(bad_combos)){
  #find the columns that match this combination
  sel = which(colnames(dat) %in% bad_combos[i,])
# identify rows we can change, looking only at the relevant columns
  tochange = rowSums(is.na(dat[,sel]))==0
  dat[tochange,sel[1]] = NA
}
```

if you need to remove minimum number of columns:

```
bad_combos <- cbind(Var1 = c("V1", "V2", "V3"),Var2=c("V4", "V4", "V4"))
lvl = names(sort(table(bad_combos),decreasing=TRUE))
sorted_combos = t(apply(bad_combos,1,function(i)sort(factor(i,levels=lvl))))
```

And repeat the above with sorted_combos.

Comment: Great that avoids looping over the whole dataset! Remaining problem though is what gets removed first. Imagine a situation where `bad_combos <- data.frame(Var1 = c("V4", "V4", "V4"), Var2 = c("V1", "V2", "V3"))` -- this could be resolved by either removing **only** "V4", or by removing **all of** "V1", "V2", "V3". I'm looking for a way to minimize the overall number of cells that have to be removed. Any ideas for a modification to do that?

Comment: I cannot really tell from a limited example, but if you look at the code above, I always remove from the first entry (sel[1]). So sorting bad_combos in a way that the most frequent column appears first will do the trick

Comment: I have added some commented code above, it should work. Also keep your bad combo as a matrix.

Comment: Agreed about sorting as a good solution. But I don't see the commented code that you said you added above. Did you forget to add that?

Comment: @TKraft, Something was wrong with my internet connection. Updated question now